# NSString retain count in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, retaincount

```
NSString* nsString=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:@"nsString"];
NSLog(@"nsString RetainCount:%li",[nsString retainCount]);
```

the corresponding result is:

```
 2013-03-04 11:18:03.291 ARC[655:303] nsString RetainCount:-1
```

in addition:
   if use init a NSMutableString instance;
   it return 1;

Comment: so what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://whentouseretaincount.com

Immutable `NSStrings` generated at compile time are singletons.  Thus, they don't do the `retain/release` dance at all.

`NSString` detects when it is initialized with such and just returns the string directly.  You'd find that the object returned by `alloc` in that code is different than the one returned by the `init...` call.

Comment: Thanks to @regexident for cleaning up formatting!